# The code does not work when there is more than one element to fill

Tags: jquery, css

The code works perfectly, but only for one element, as follows it is filled according to the percentage.

```js
$(function () {
    $("div.percent").each(function(){
        var s = $("span.pct").text() + ' 100%';
        $(this).css({"background-size": s})
        console.log(s);
    });
});
```

```css
.avg-percent {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.very-satisfied {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #57bb8a, #57bb8a);
}

.percent {
    width: 90%;
    background-size: 1% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.percent span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
span.avg-vote {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avg-percent div flex relative">
    <div class="percent very-satisfied">
        <span class="pct">70%</span>
        <span class="avg-vote">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here comes the problem, when there are more elements that you want to fill, the code stops working.

```js
$(function () {
    $("div.percent").each(function(){
        var s = $("span.pct").text() + ' 100%';
        $(this).css({"background-size": s})
        console.log(s);
    });
});
```

```css
.avg-percent {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.very-satisfied {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #57bb8a, #57bb8a);
}

.percent {
    width: 90%;
    background-size: 1% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.percent span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
span.avg-vote {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avg-percent div flex relative">
    <div class="percent very-satisfied">
        <span class="pct">60%</span>
        <span class="avg-vote">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="avg-percent div flex relative">
    <div class="percent very-satisfied">
        <span class="pct">40%</span>
        <span class="avg-vote">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the first example where only a single element is evaluated, in the console it shows us this `70% 100%` but when I want to use multipli in the console it shows me this `60%40% 100%` `60%40% 100%`

So how can I get the code to work for multiple background padding?

Comment: Try `$("span.pct", this).text()` to make sure you're selecting a child element

Comment: @Phil I have added it directly to my second code of my question, it does not work friend

Comment: Please look closer, that is not the syntax I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the specific `span.pct` within the target element.

```js
$(function () {
    $("div.percent").each(function(){
        var s = $(this).find("span.pct").text() + ' 100%'; // Change this line
        $(this).css({"background-size": s})
        console.log(s);
    });
});
```

```css
.avg-percent {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.very-satisfied {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #57bb8a, #57bb8a);
}

.percent {
    width: 90%;
    background-size: 1% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.percent span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
span.avg-vote {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avg-percent div flex relative">
    <div class="percent very-satisfied">
        <span class="pct">60%</span>
        <span class="avg-vote">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="avg-percent div flex relative">
    <div class="percent very-satisfied">
        <span class="pct">40%</span>
        <span class="avg-vote">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```